# How to implement a MIMO model with state space block in sumulink?

Tags: control-system, matlab, simulink

I want to implement an state space model with 4 inputs and 4 outputs at simulink. But the state space block has only one input and only one output. So what can I do here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out just now. So all we have to use is a mux block for the input and demux block for outputs. 
[image]

Comment: Also, if you want a good reference for a MIMO implementation in Simulink, "Lattice Reduction for MIMO Detection: From Theoretical Analysis to Hardware Realization" by Gestner and Anderson has Simulink description of the system that you can download if you need help getting started.